How can I keep my view centered on the user's finger during drag
I have a cursor icon that I'd like to keep centered on the user's finger as they drag it, but due to touch slop and a variety of other things, it doesn't stay centered by simply updating the view's offset via the drag amount in onDrag.
I thought I could compute the global X Y of the touch point and just set it to that but it's oddly difficult to get that value in Compose without doing discouraged things like using the pointerInterop modifier.
     onDrag = { change, dragAmount ->
                    change.consume()

                    params.x += dragAmount.x.toInt()
                    params.y += dragAmount.y.toInt()
                    wm.updateViewLayout(composeView, params)
                   
                }

UPDATE 1
There's gotta be some obvious math I'm just not seeing.  I'm able to sync the view's centerpoint with the user's finger on DragStart by shifting the view by the offset like here:
onDragStart = {
    params.x = params.x + it.x.toInt() - (composeView.width / 2)
    params.y = params.y + it.y.toInt() - (composeView.height / 2)
    wm.updateViewLayout(composeView, params)
},
onDrag = { change, dragAmount ->
    change.consume()
    //cant do that here though so doing the normal way below
    // params.x = params.x + change.position.x.toInt() - (composeView.width / 2)
    // params.y = params.y + change.position.y.toInt() - (composeView.height / 2)
    params.x += dragAmount.x.toInt()
    params.y += dragAmount.y.toInt()
   
    wm.updateViewLayout(composeView, params)
}

If I comment out the dragamount incremental way and use the adjusted way, it goes erratic when you drag it, jumping around crazy.
I tried some other techniques like using awaitEachGesture (seen below) with drag to get rid of the touch slop detection but that doesn't get me any closer.
The real problem seems to occur when the user drags VERY slow.  If you drag very slow, for some reason your finger is allowed to creep away from the view.  It's like the view doesn't respond to very tiny movements.
All I want to do is keep the view centered on the touch point. It seems like it should just be some formula with existing available params..
 .pointerInput(Unit) {
                awaitEachGesture {
                    val down = awaitFirstDown()

                    drag(down.id) { change ->
                        val posChange = change.positionChange()
                        val pos = change.position
                        Log.i("await gesture drag", "change: ${pos}")
                        Log.i("await gesture drag", "poschange: ${posChange}")
                        change.consume()
                        params.x += posChange.x.toInt()
                        params.y += posChange.y.toInt()
                       // params.x = params.x + pos.x.toInt() - (composeView.width / 2)
                       // params.y = params.y + pos.y.toInt() - (composeView.height / 2)
                        wm.updateViewLayout(composeView, params)
                    }

                }
            }

I also created this GIF to show the issues.
First you can see the touch point has some drift even if I go fast.  It goes to the edge of the circle.  Then worse, if I go really slow, it drifts a lot.
Update 2
I just realized it might be because the drag amount has to be rounded to an int for the layout params x and y.  I'll investigate that tomorrow.
imgur GIF of issue
Update 3
My theory about rounding was correct.  When you drag very slowly, the change position/drag amount float .toInt() was rounding down to zero and causing no movement.  Changing it to roundToInt also doesnt work because then slow movements slowly crawl past your finger as it rounds up.  The solution for me was to use a float accumulator so that the small drag amounts aren't swallowed.  I'm guessing this is because I'm moving around a parent ComposeView rather than from the touched element's own .offset modifier?
I'm not really sure what the difference is because I know you don't need an accumulator for the usual drag technique, maybe theres a hidden accumulator under the hood?
            .pointerInput(Unit) {

                val center = size.center

                awaitEachGesture {
                    val down = awaitFirstDown()

                    params.x += (down.position.x - center.x).roundToInt()
                    params.y += (down.position.y - center.y).roundToInt() 
                    wm.updateViewLayout(composeView, params)

                    drag(down.id) { change ->
                        val posChange = change.positionChange()

                        change.consume()

                        accumulatedX += posChange.x
                        accumulatedY += posChange.y

                        val deltaX = accumulatedX.toInt()
                        val deltaY = accumulatedY.toInt()

                        accumulatedX -= deltaX
                        accumulatedY -= deltaY

                        params.x += deltaX
                        params.y += deltaY
                        wm.updateViewLayout(composeView, params)
                    }

                }
            }


If it's possible to add touch gesture on parent you can check if touched position is in your composeView and check drag as
Result

@Preview
@Composable
fun DragFromCenterTest() {

    var offset by remember {
        mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero)
    }

    var childSize by remember {
        mutableStateOf(IntSize.Zero)
    }

    var isTouched by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()

            .pointerInput(Unit) {

                awaitEachGesture {
                    val down = awaitFirstDown()

                    val position = down.position
                    isTouched = position.minus(offset)
                        .getDistanceSquared() < childSize.width * childSize.width
                    do {

                        //This PointerEvent contains details including
                        // event, id, position and more
                        val event: PointerEvent = awaitPointerEvent()

                        event.changes.firstOrNull()?.let { pointerInputChange ->
                            if (isTouched) {

                                val position = pointerInputChange.position
                                
                                offset =
                                    Offset(
                                        position.x - childSize.width / 2,
                                        position.y - childSize.height / 2
                                    )
                            }
                        }


                    } while (event.changes.any { it.pressed })
                }

                // Alternative 2 with drag
//                detectDragGestures(
//                    onDragStart = { position ->
//                         isTouched = position.minus(offset)
//                            .getDistanceSquared() < childSize.width * childSize.width
//
//                        if (isTouched) {
//                            offset =
//                                Offset(
//                                    position.x - childSize.width / 2,
//                                    position.y - childSize.height / 2
//                                )
//                        }
//                    },
//                    onDrag = { change, dragAmount ->
//
//                        val position = change.position
//
//                        if (isTouched) {
//                            offset =
//                                Offset(
//                                    position.x - childSize.width / 2,
//                                    position.y - childSize.height / 2
//                                )
//                        }
//                    }
//                )
            }
    ) {

        Draggable(
            modifier = Modifier
                .onSizeChanged {
                    childSize = it
                }
                .offset {
                    IntOffset(offset.x.toInt(), offset.y.toInt())
                }
                .drawWithContent {
                    drawContent()
                    drawCircle(
                        color = Color.Red,
                        radius = 10.dp.toPx()
                    )
                }
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun Draggable(
    modifier: Modifier,
) {
    Box(modifier.size(100.dp).background(Color.Blue, CircleShape))
}

If you wish to add gesture to child you need to calculate distance of first touch to center of your Composable which is as
@Preview
@Composable
fun DragFromCenterTest2() {

    var offset by remember {
        mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero)
    }

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {

        Draggable(
            modifier = Modifier

                .offset {
                    IntOffset(offset.x.toInt(), offset.y.toInt())
                }

                .pointerInput(Unit) {

                    val size = size
                    val center = size.center
                    awaitEachGesture {

                        val down = awaitFirstDown()

                        val firstDown = down.position

                        val distanceToCenter =
                            Offset(firstDown.x - center.x, firstDown.y - center.y)
                        // Move current position to first down position to center it at first
                        // touch position
                        offset += distanceToCenter

                        do {

                            val event: PointerEvent = awaitPointerEvent()

                            event.changes.firstOrNull()?.let { pointerInputChange ->

                                val position = pointerInputChange.positionChange()

                                offset += position

                            }

                        } while (event.changes.any { it.pressed })
                    }
                }
                .drawWithContent {
                    drawContent()
                    drawCircle(
                        color = Color.Red,
                        radius = 10.dp.toPx()
                    )
                }
        )
    }
}


The issue is identical to this one but unlike the comments, deploying to a hardware device is not sufficient.  there is always a bit of shifting that I dont want. The view needs to stay locked on to their finger.  Some lag is okay if they move super fast but it should ultimately catch up and stop centered on the finger tip.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77799605/how-to-make-dragged-item-follow-pointer-position-without-latency-in-android-jetp

You mean touch draw latency. In that case first thing you can do is using a move event instead of drag. You can refer this answer for more details. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70847531/5457853. However there still be a latency while moving your finger. This happens in most of the apps on device as well.

I guess its similar to draw latency although the user isn't drawing.  They're moving a mouse-like cursor around to point at things, and if there's any drift, their finger might cover the UI which is bad.  The UI needs to stay centered on their finger tip similar to how the android debug "Pointer location" setting draws a circle with crosshair around the touch point.  I'm checking out your repo now.  Thanks for your great work on that.  I just the minimum effective change to keep the UI centered.

Yes, using a gesture that is not drag has the default latency while moving but minus the one from initial touchSlope check which requires to move a minimum amount before invoking onDragStart. If you apply the solution in Codelab you can improve graphic pipeline so latency will be even smaller. You should test out codelab code, but that's the lowest latency you can get i suppose, unless there isn't anything else causing recomposition or layout delays, etc. If you also mean codelab link, it's official repo, not mine. Mine is drawing app.

I was talking about you SmartToolFactory repo for all the compose concepts.

Ok, thanks then.

I edited my post to include more context and status update.   The issue is more obvious when you drag very slowly. For some reason that allows your finger to drift the most from the view.

@joepetrakovich added new code with both drag and onTouchEvent gesture. If you don't want to add touch gesture to parent it would be more tricky since you are moving gesture position as well.

Added another sample that gesture is added to child.

Not included but if you wish to constrain area draggable can move just add offset.x.coerceIn(0, parentWidth -childWidth/2) for width and height too.

I ended up needing to use a float accumulator for the drag amounts since they were rounding down to zero and causing no movement.  I'm guessing because I'm dragging a parent view from the child so something is different about how Compose handles rounding in that scenario?  Not really sure.  Thanks for your help!  I used your technique for centering the touch point so I will accept your answer.
